# How to plot multiple pandas dataframe as separate categories in a violinplot?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am reading data from four separate files of different categories and would like to visualize the distribution of a filed for those using a violin plot. In my attempt, it seems like they are getting overwritten

```
import seaborn as sb

# category1, category2, category3, category4 are pandas dataFrame obj

sb.violinplot(category1['delay'])
sb.violinplot(category2['delay'])
sb.violinplot(category3['delay'])
sb.violinplot(category4['delay'])
```

Comment: plt.violinplot(dataset = df.values)

Answer (score 3):

You may try:

```
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': np.random.rand(100), 'col2': np.random.rand(100)})
sns.violinplot(data=df);
```

[image]

or, if you need to combine several df's of yours:

```
df = pd.concat([category1['delay'],
                category2['delay'],
                category3['delay'],
                category4['delay']],
                axis=1)
sns.violinplot(data=df);
```